# Elasticsearch: two fields ranges query

Tags: elasticsearch, range, aggregation

I have a series of ranges, let's say [1-5], [6-10], [11-15].
What I'm looking for are, **for each range**, records whose "start" field is before the first element in the range, and whose "end" field is after the second element in the range.

Using elasticsearch, I can accomplish this for a single range by the following query:

```
GET my_index/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "end": {
                      "gte": 5
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "start": {
                      "lte": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "value": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "value",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How could I accomplish this with **multiple** ranges in one query?

In pseudo-code it would be something like,

```
 for each range: 
   must:
      start < range[0],
      end > range[1]
```

Test data:

```
PUT /test_index
{"settings": {"number_of_shards": 1}}

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"start":0, "end":10, "value":2}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"start":0, "end":12, "value":1}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"start":2, "end":11, "value":2}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"start":11, "end":13, "value":3}
```

Expected output:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "my_ranges": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "1-5", # i.e. range 1-5
               "doc_count": 2,
               "value": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "2",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "6-10", # i.e. range 6-10
               "doc_count": 1,
               "value": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "2",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you not just add more `"range"` clauses to your `"must"`?

Comment: The thing is, I want the results separated/bucketed for each range.

Comment: are you looking for [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html)?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 interesting idea, although can you incorporate the interval values in the filters?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements right and assuming your range field is `integer`, then [Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) aggregation will do.
Try this

```
   {
      "aggs": {
        "ranges": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "range",
            "interval": 5
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "value",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 0
    }
```

Comment: I like the clean structure of the query, but it needs to filter such that field "start" is **less than** the interval start, and field "end" is **greater than** the interval end...?

Comment: Hmm, I am not exactly sure how to achieve that :( although some sample document and desired output will give us better idea

Comment: I added some sample data and desired output :).

Comment: I think you need to use `filters aggregation` but if you have lot of ranges then it will be ugly. I am not aware of any other way.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ChintanShah25, I appreciate it!